# Laravel - Redirect users to custom urls based on language field on login form

Tags: laravel, authentication, localization, multilingual

I have a **Laravel** project with the basic (artisan) auth created.
I have added a **language field** to the `login.blade.php` view.

I would like to catch that language variable from the login form and **redirect users after login** to
`myawesomewebsite/{$language}`

(`myawesomewebsite/en` or `myawesomewebsite/fr`).

***I have no idea how to catch this data.***

I think it would be nice if I am able to store this language variable in the sessions and then I could use this code to redirect the user to my routes. I'm using this code in my `LoginController.php` so far.

```
public function authenticated(Request $request)
{
    $lang = $request->session()->get('user_language', 'default');
    $route = '/' . $lang;
    return redirect($route);
}
```

, but if you know some other way better, please share it. *Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a language input field in the form, you can just use:

`$request->input('user_language', 'default');`

Other than that, your code should work as long as you have a route supporting the language.

Comment: Thank you, but in what file can I use that snippet??, I'm a newbie on Laravel
I already have routes that support:
myawesomewebsite/en/about | 
myawesomewebsite/es/acerca-de

Comment: Just replace `$request->session()->get('user_language', 'default');` from your LoginController.php example, with what I wrote.

Comment: Please read this article https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/